# How to Integrate UWP with RDP

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I was looking for a way to integrate MS remote desktop client with UWP, in the past I read somewhere that was possible in WPF. Can ne done with UWP?

Comment: anyone?........

Comment: you mean you just need to launch the mstsc.exe in your UWP APP?

Comment: No, I mean hosting a Microsoft RDP client control in UWP app. I n WPF this was possible. (here's an example https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET?msg=4777187)

Comment: There's no such a  Microsoft RDP client control in UWP.

Comment: H Xavieri, does Microsoft plan to have an RDP control to use with in UWP soon?

Comment: We're planning to migrate from WPF to UWP, and we need to integrate this control in the new app... it would be nice if MS had a control that we could integrate in UWP, or any other way to migrate that control from WPF to UWP